# What firmware components of a PC are writeable?

Tags: virus, rootkits, firmware

What firmware components of a PC are writable?  For instance which components have the ability to store rootkits or viruses?

Comment: Writable from within the operating system, or by a person with physical access?

Comment: You probably meant "could be writable". Whether they are or not depends on each individual product. You could create an ASIC for a keyboard that wouldn't contain any writable persistent storage.

Comment: If a component contains writable storage, this storage might be rewritten while the machine is running even though this is not an intended feature. 

Rewriting thru physical access is of course a lot worse. And you don't necessarily have to bother rewriting [on the spot] if you can swap.

Answer (score 1):

Technically every device or system component that contains persistent writable storage w.g. flash memory is also writable:

- UEFI/BIOS - well known, can be flashed by various tools provided by manufacturer

  - Intel Management Engine Firmware (usually included in system UEFI firmware)
- HDD firmware
- SSD firmware
- Controller firmware (e.g. RAID controller)
- Graphic card firmware
- Network controller firmware
- Connected USB devices

  - Wireless mouse/keyboard controller firmware
  - USB stick firmware
- ...

Nowadays nearly every controller or device inside or outside of a computer has a flash chip that stores it's firmware. As there is no central interface for accessing those firmware chips you would have to check each device type, manufacturer and model and then check how to get access to the firmware.

Note that writing to some those flash memory systems may be protected e.g. data to be written have to be signed using a cryptographic signature. Also the API used to write the firmware is often not public (which doesn't prevent people form reverse engineer it).

Comment: Not all of these can be written to from the operating system in all cases. Many connected USB devices have firmware that cannot be written to over USB, and many GPUs and NICs don't allow flashing new firmware onto the card from the OS. And UEFI/BIOS, while it can usually be written to, usually has a component that is read-only called the CRTM which can be used to bootstrap integrity measurement of remaining firmware.

Comment: @forest Historically, there's been many vulnerabilities found which have let attackers write where they shouldn't be able to. Some devices do not offer a way to write their persistent storage. These would be safe. But vulnerabilities in a microcontroller could let an attack rewrite part or all of its flash memory even when the original firmware would not have any provision for firmware update.

Comment: Probably falls under the category "controller", but can I add that if you have RGB LED thingies, they most likely have some flash associated... Basically, if it's electronic, and in particular if it includes a micro-controller, most likely, it has flash and can be rewritten. Notable exception would be your typical PSU.

Comment: @forest Not all of those components have writable flash firmware, but in each category there are a decent number of devices that can be flashed. And what is worse once flashed with a compromised firmware often such devices can't be reflashed, they just claim to flash a new firmware but actually don't write the new firmware.

Comment: @user1532080 Vulnerabilities of that sort do exist, but in many cases it's simply impossible to flash from software. A vulnerability in, say, an 8051 microcontroller won't let you re-flash it because it simply can't re-flash itself unless it asserts a particular pin which may be pulled low. My point is just that the implication that all of these can be flashed from software is a bit misleading.